# Android webview very strange behavior

Tags: android, css, android-layout, webview

In landscape mode I got a horizontal layout that wrap a some button on the left and a webview on the right like this:

[image]

Everything work well in WebView till an absolute or fixed element is added to it.

For example this element

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:30px; background:#ff0000"></div>
```

This is how it appears:

[image]

As you see there is a gap on the right, exactly with the size of layout on the left. Actually the div width is the full webview width minus buttons layout width.

This is how it turns if the buttons layout width increase:

[image]

This breaks many thing, for example iscroll.

I tried but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Remove `width:100%` and add `right: 0;`

Comment: @Andy the problem is width, not positioning. this way gap will be on the left. Anyway, I can't fix it for iscroll.

Comment: No, if you specify `left: 0; right: 0;` it will make it stretch 100% width

Comment: @Andy what can I do for iscroll?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Samsung ICS tablets and had to disable hardware acceleration. position, overflow and translate3d CSS were all failing due to this.

Turn it off in the manifest

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

or disable it programatically

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    myWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```